# How to fit IMG in parent DIV where its height is not set?

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have this situation: I want to make a IMG height to be fit with its parent DIV where no height is set. This is the sample code:

```css
.box_NewsList {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffa;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box_NewsList>img {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box_NewsPreview {
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
.box_NewsPreview>.tit_News {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: -15px 0 15px;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  background: transparent url(../imgs/main_menu_hover.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_NewsList">
  <img class="pull-left" src="mypicture.jpg">
  <div class="box_NewsPreview">
    <h1 class="tit_News">MyTitle</h1>
    <div class="txt_Abstract">
      <p>Long text abstract here</p>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded pull-right">READ</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make the img height to fit the height of div with `box_NewsPreview` class?

```
.box_NewsPreview>.txt_Abstract p{color:#7e7e7e;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;font-size:1rem;font-weight:300;text-align:justify;}
```

**If I add a height value in `box_NewsList` like `height:300px;` it works fine.**

If I set `height:auto`, `height:initial`, `height:inherit` or I don't add any height value in that class then I get the IMG in its full size instead of resizing in its parent height.

Comment: How do you want the image to be positioned, next to the text or?

Comment: Next the text. Class `pull-left` contains `float:left;`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div class="box_NewsList">
   <div class="box_NewsPreview">
   <img class="pull-left" src="mypicture.jpg" stretch="fill">
      <h1 class="tit_News">MyTitle</h1>
      <div class="txt_Abstract"><p>Long text abstract here</p></div>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded pull-right">READ</button>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

It looks like `<img>` was inside news_list not news_preview.
I added stretch to the img, so no matter what it will always stretch to the size of the div :)

Comment: it might not be what you wanted, but yea, then i just misunderstood.

Comment: I tried and I have the same thing. If no height is set to `box_newsPreview`, the IMG height is set to full size.

Comment: if you are really lazy you could probably just create a function that sets the visibility of the image to false if the height of the div is <= 0

Comment: other than that i have no idea why the image is maximizing

Comment: I'm not lazy, of course, but if I can do the trick via CSS is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to acheive what you want is to use a little jQuery. I dont think it is possible with pure CSS

I have made an example where i set `position: relative;` on `.box_NewsList` and `position: absolute;` on `.box_NewsList>img`

and the this little script to loop through the images and give padding to the text:

```
$('.box_NewsList').each(function() {
    var imageWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
  $(this).find('.box_NewsPreview').css('padding-left', imageWidth + 15);
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a0Lf84h/)

Comment: Yes, I think that a jQuery function is the way. This is may own code:
   $('.box_NewsList').each(function() {
      var theHeight = $(this).height();
      $(this).find('img').css('height',theHeight+'px');
   });

and I set the img height to 0 in the CSS